# Re-Assigning values on a pandas DataFrame best practice

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on the Medical Data Visualizer challenge and I am reassigning DataFrame values based on some conditions, like this :

```
df['cholesterol'].loc[df['cholesterol'] == 1] = 0 #normalizing cholestrol values
df['cholesterol'].loc[df['cholesterol'] > 1] = 1 #normalizing cholestrol values
```

It seems to work, however , I am also working with Jupyter Notebooks and when I load the snipet with this code I get the following warning :

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:670: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

Now, even though it works, I am wondering if this is the best way to do it (best practice) or there is other way I should reassign those values.

Looking for the best practice on this subject to not cause future errors.

Thank you

EDIT :

```
id  age gender  height  weight  ap_hi   ap_lo   cholesterol gluc    smoke   alco    active  cardio
    0   18393   2   168 62.0    110 80  1   1   0   0   1   0
    1   20228   1   156 85.0    140 90  3   1   0   0   1   1
    2   18857   1   165 64.0    130 70  3   1   0   0   0   1
    3   17623   2   169 82.0    150 100 1   1   0   0   1   1
    4   17474   1   156 56.0    100 60  1   1   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: But my goal is not to create a copy, is just to change the original dataframe cells that meet those conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference: [Why does assignment fail when using chained indexing?](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing)

Use:

```
#        subset index          subset columns
df.loc[df['cholesterol'] == 1, 'cholesterol'] = 0
df.loc[df['cholesterol'] > 1, 'cholesterol'] = 1
print(df)

# Output
   cholesterol
0            0
1            1
2            1
```

This will avoid `SettingWithCopyWarning` because there is no chained subsetting.

Setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'cholesterol': [1, 2, 3]})
print(df)

# Output
   cholesterol
0            1
1            2
2            3
```

**Update**

With your sample:

```
>>> df[['id', 'age', 'cholesterol']]
   id    age  cholesterol
0   0  18393            0
1   1  20228            1
2   2  18857            1
3   3  17623            0
4   4  17474            0

>>> df
   id    age  gender  height  weight  ap_hi  ap_lo  cholesterol  gluc  smoke  alco  active  cardio
0   0  18393       2     168    62.0    110     80            0     1      0     0       1       0
1   1  20228       1     156    85.0    140     90            1     1      0     0       1       1
2   2  18857       1     165    64.0    130     70            1     1      0     0       0       1
3   3  17623       2     169    82.0    150    100            0     1      0     0       1       1
4   4  17474       1     156    56.0    100     60            0     1      0     0       0       0
```

Comment: @Simao. Does it solve your problem?

Comment: I tried this, but it changes the values on all columns for some reason. Like, it doesn't change only the values that meet the conditions. I am creating the DF from a CSV file btw

Comment: It's not possible if you select the columns `cholesterol`. Can you update your post with the output of `df.head()`?

Comment: If you use a condition like `> 1`, except if the value is 0, all values will be set to 1.

Comment: I find it weird too, still trying to understand why it changes the values for ALL column

Comment: You forgot the second `cholesterol` (columns) in `df.loc[df['cholesterol'] == 1, 'cholesterol']`

Comment: Spotted the problem, I believe I was was missing the second argument on df.loc[df['gluc'] == 1] and somehow was changing the entire DF.

Comment: Yes, that was it. Can you explain what the second argument is for btw, cause that was the cause of the issue.

Comment: The first argument of `loc` is to subset the rows rather than the second one is to subset the columns. (like x, y)